# How to fix this regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

i have a regular expression to remove certain parts from a URI. However it doesn't take into account multiple parts in a way that works :-). Can somebody assist?

```
$regex = '~/{(.*?)}\*~'

$uri = '/user/{action}/{id}*/{subAction}*';
$newuri = preg_replace($regex, ''  , $uri); 

//$newuri = /user/
//Should be: $newuri = /user/{action}/
```

I know it matches the following part as one match:

> /{action}/{id}*/{subAction}*

But it should match the following two seperately:

> /{id}*
>
> /{subAction}*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me it looks like your `{(.*?)}\*` test is matching all of `{action}/{id}*`, which judging from what you've written isn't what you want.

So change the Kleene closure to be less greedy:

```
'~/{([^}]*)}\*~'
```

But do you really need to capture the part inside the curly braces? Seems to me you could go with this one instead:

```
'~/{[^}]*}\*~'
```

Either way, the `[^}]*` part guarantees that the expression will not match `{action}/` because it doesn't end in an asterisk.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along! This is exactly what i need!